# java casting with superclass reference

Tags: java, casting

Can someone explain what's happening here?

Assume `Car` and `Bike` are subclasses of `Vehicle`.

It looks to me like `Vehicle v` reference gets cast to a `Bike`. I know this is illegal and indeed the compiler spits out `... Car cannot be cast to Bike`.

But shouldn't this be `Vehicle` cannot be cast to `Bike`? After all, `Vehicle v` is a `Vehicle` reference.

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Vehicle v = new Car();
       Bike b = (Bike) v;
       // some stuff
    }   
}
```

Comment: Because JVM knows that it is a Car when it is throwing the exception.

Comment: The compiler doesn't split out the exception. The code throws a **runtime** `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @Pregnant mom, please accept an answer if you have are happy with any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message says `Car` because this is run time exception. Since by this time it knows the actual instance (Car, Bike, or Vehicle) the Vehicle reference is pointing to, it gives more specific error message.

If this is some exception at compile time, compiler would have mentioned `Vehicle` since compiler may not know the actual instance the Vehicle reference is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a `Car` that is being cast. `v` is of type `Vehicle` so the assignment of `Vehicle v = new Car();` works since a `Car` is a `Vehicle`.

The object `v` retains its identity; that being a `Car`. So  the illegal cast is from `Car` to `Bike`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Bike b = (Bike) v;
```

would be legal if, say, `v` was a passed-in `Vehicle`.  So I would guess that this validation is happening in the process of optimization.  The compiler wants to optimize away the normal work in casting if it can - maybe even optimize away `b` altogether - and of course it *could* if `v` had been created as a `Bike` on the previous line, instead of a `Car`.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, that line is valid if and only if v is a Bike object (or instance of a subclass) regardless of where the v object comes from.

Answer (score 0):

A (semi) plain-english response:

A Car cannot suddenly "become" a Bike or be treated like a bike, because a Bike would have different properties (variables) *describing* it, and different ways to *interact* with it (methods).

However, they are both vehicles, so they would have some things in common, such as perhaps, ability to steer, turn left or right, or change gears.

This makes it simple when you have logic like this:

```
ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
vehicles.add(new Bike());
vehicles.add(new Car());
vehicles.add(new Bike());

//Some other crazy code

for(Vehicle v : vehicles) {
    v.applyBrakes();
    v.changeDownGear();
    v.turnRight();
}
```

each subclass of Vehicle (Bike,Car,Segway etc) would have their own implementation of those methods and handle themselves appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Without having the source code it's impossible to definitively say what's legal and what's not.  However, it's safe to assume that the inheritance tree for these classes looks something like

> ```
>     Vehicle
>        |
>   __________
>   |         |
>  Car      Bike
> ```

Such that `Car` and `Bike` are subclasses of `Vehicle` which means that `Vehicle` is a generalization of `Car` and `Bike`.  In Java, you can cast an instance of a subclass into it's base class.  So in this case you can cast a `Car` to a vehicle and treat it like you actually had an instance of a `Vehicle` object.  The same is true with a `Bike`. However, because `Car` is not a subclass of `Bike` you cannot cast from one to the other.  All `Cars` are `Vehicles` but not all `Vehicles` are `Cars`.  Nor are they `Bikes`.  And a `Car` is never a `Bike` and vice versa.

You do this to create code that is more extensible.  For instance you can write code that understands how to interact with code that will be written in the future.  An example of this would be some common interface, such as `drive()` that allows other developers to provide custom implementations later on.  Your code though, written before hand can still work with it because it can treat the new subclasses as if they were instances of the base class.